# Solution for the vector equation $ r + (r \cdot a) b = c$

Tags: vectors

How to find the solution of $r+(r \cdot a)b =c$, where $a,b$ and $c$ are fixed vectors. I found out one solution when $a \cdot b$ is not equal to $-1$. But how to find the solution when $a\cdot b=-1$?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not $a \cdot b = -1$, we can take a cross product with $b$ to get the equation

$$r \times b = c \times b \implies (r-c) \times b = 0$$

This [implies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Algebraic_properties) that either $b=0$, $r-c = 0$, or $r-c = \lambda b$ for some non-zero $\lambda$. Substituting that into the original equation gives an equation for $\lambda$,

$$\lambda b + c + \lambda (b\cdot a) b + (c \cdot a) b = c \implies \lambda(1+b\cdot a) + c\cdot a =0$$

Thus there are four cases:

- $b=0$ and $r=c$.
- $b \ne 0$ and $a\cdot b \ne -1$ and there is a unique solution for $\lambda$.
- $a \cdot b = -1$ and $c \cdot a \ne 0$, and there are no solutions,
- $a \cdot b = -1$ and $c \cdot a = 0$, and any value of $\lambda$ gives a solution.